# Viewshed curvature of Earth using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, viewshed, geodesy

I've been running some viewshed analyses in ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 and a few of these involve results at extreme ranges (200km+). This is set in a mountainous region with a few especially dominant features, but I did some distance to horizon at altitude math and some of the results seem to be beyond the horizon. [ESRI's documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/viewshed-global-function.htm) says the viewshed function "always considers the curvature of the earth" but I'm starting to wonder. My map does not have a Z spatial reference defined, but defining one (EGM2008) and running some more viewsheds only creates errors.

Is there a better way to consider the horizon in very long viewshed examinations?